# Is there an easy way to write a complex class' object into a file for java?

Tags: java

Suppose I have something like this:

```
class A
{
public B mem;
public int x;
public int y;
}

class B
{
public C mem1;
public D mem2;
}

class C
{
public Image img;
}

class D
{
public int m;
}


//Writing object A onto a file using ObjectWriter?
```

How would I write class A onto a file with ObjectWriter? If I directly write it, then it will only copy the pointer (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: and you probably ment to write `private ...` on your member variables

Comment: @Viper  I 'disagree' in the sense that may or may not be what the OP intended, but for purposes of serialization by the `ObjectOutputStream` or `XMLEcnoder`, private fields would typically not be stored (AFAIU).

Comment: I didn't say that he must/should either, and wouldn't it be serialized unless he adds transcient on the fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Use [the serialization API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). It's pretty dead simple.

Comment: Does it work if the member of the class is a pointer of a pointer to another class (like A contain pointer B which contain pointer C)? Won't it just write down the pointer instead of the raw data?

Comment: hey @user385261 that Image class just need to implement Serializable just as your classes should. Don't worry